# Question to multi-component fluids

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, plasma-physics, continuum-mechanics

I have read these lecture notes:
[http://geo.mff.cuni.cz/~soucek/vyuka/materials/theory-of-mixtures/theory_of_mixtures-lecture-notes.pdf](http://geo.mff.cuni.cz/%7Esoucek/vyuka/materials/theory-of-mixtures/theory_of_mixtures-lecture-notes.pdf)

Now look at page 41: There are 4 different types of mixture theory. In physics, there can appear Type III theories, for example plasma physics balance equations:

$\partial _t c_p + \nabla(c_p v_p)= 0$ (1a)

$\partial _t c_n + \nabla(c_p v_n)= 0$ (1b)

$\partial _t (c_p v_p) + \nabla(c_p v_p \otimes v_p + T_p) + b_p + \pi_p = 0$ (2a)

$\partial _t (c_n v_n) + \nabla(c_p v_n \otimes v_n + T_n) + b_n + \pi_n = 0$ (2b)

$\partial _t (e_p + c_p v_p^2 /2) + \nabla((e_p + c_p v_p^2 /2) v_p + T_pv_p + q_p) + b_pv_p+\xi_p= 0$ (3a)

$\partial _t (e_n + c_n v_n^2 /2) + \nabla((e_n + c_n v_n^2 /2) v_n + T_nv_n + q_n) + b_nv_n+\xi_n= 0$ (3b)

$\partial_t s + \nabla J \geq 0$ (4)

Here,

subscripts 'p' is for positive charged component, 'n' is for negative charged component

$c$: Concentration of species

$v$: Velocity (vector in more than 1 dimension)

$T$: Stress tensor, often in form $T = -p1 + T'$ with pressure $p$, unit tensor $1$ and non-equilibrium stress $T'$

$b$: Body force, often electromagnetic $b=qcE + qcv \times B$ with charge $q$, electric field $E$ and magnetic field $B$

$\pi$: Momentum transfer rate between species, Constraint: $\pi_n+\pi_p = 0$

$e$: Energy per unit mass

$q$: Heat flow

$\xi$ : Transfer rate of energy in-between species, Constraint (1st law of thermodynamics): $\xi_n+\xi_p = 0$

$s$: Entropy density per unit mass for whole fluid

$J$: Entropy flow for whole fluid

Equation (1) is mass conservation, (2) momentum conservation and (3) 1st law of thermodynamics. The 2nd law of thermodynamics (4) could be generalized to a type IV theory as follows:

$s_p + \nabla J_p + \lambda_p = 0$ (5a)

$s_n + \nabla J_n + \lambda_n = 0$ (5b)

$\lambda_p + \lambda_n \geq 0$ (5c)

The entropy change rate is denoted by $\lambda$. Are there already theories with an entropy balance equation for each species like (5)? It is interesting, because one may propose thermodynamic relations in the form

$s_p = s_p(e_p,e_n,c_p,c_n,v_p,v_n,\dots), s_n = s_n(e_p,e_n,c_p,c_n,v_p,v_n,\dots)$

instead of the ordinary $s = s(e_p,e_n,c_p,c_n,v_p,v_n,\dots)$ for the whole system. When substituting (1)-(3) one obtains a restriction which material laws for $p,T',\pi,q,\xi$ must hold.
If it would be a type IV theory, then we have also to propose a relation for $\lambda$.

How would such a theory look like and is it realistic? One or more species would lose their entropy because of another, creating (temporarily) order in the system.

Comment: Quick question:  What precisely is it you are looking for?  That is, what would  you like to know?  Yes, one could construct a multi-fluid model for a plasma, which people often do.  The problem is that most plasmas (by volume) in the universe are at best weakly collisional or even effectively collisionless.  This means that many of the approximations used in fluid theories start to run into trouble...

Comment: I ask whether there exist entropy balances for every constituent of the fluid